# `Screen.pixelDensity` equals 0 in non-visual components

Tags: qt, properties, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I want to use `Screen.pixelDensity` in QML to calculate the size of my visual components. In order to keep an element's properties in one place (there are a couple of them) I created a container object:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item
{
    readonly property double constantValue: 100 * Screen.pixelDensity
    property double first
    property double second: first + constantValue

    // and so on

    Component.onCompleted: console.log(Screen.pixelDensity) // (1)
}
```

When the object is initialized, the statement (1) reports that `Screen.pixelDensity == 0`

If I put the same statement in my main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow
{
    title: qsTr("title")
    width: 480
    height: 800

    // some visual stuff here

    Component.onCompleted: console.log("testing: "  + Screen.pixelDensity)
}
```

then `Screen.pixelDensity` is reported to be non-zero, as expected.

Why does the property misbehave in the first case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [QML doc for `Screen`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-screen.html#details)

> The Screen attached object is valid inside Item or Item derived types, after component completion. Inside these items **it refers to the screen that the item is currently being displayed on.**

If the item is not displayed <sup>(that's what I understood from your question)</sup> then the information can't be reached... Thus it displays 0.